# Abstract class with no abstract methods inside

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Is there a class in Java(JDK) with no abstract methods inside but still declared as an abstract class?

Answer (score 3):

sure, [javax.swing.AbstractAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html)

Comment: AbstractAction doesn't have any abstract methods inside, which is what you asked for, but it inherits and doesn't implement 'actionPerformed' from interface 'ActionListener' and i guess that classifies as an abstract method, for an abstract class without any abstract methods at all, see javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder

Comment: It certainly qualifies ... according to the OP's requirements.